# how do i keep track of how many times a number is rolled?

Tags: python

I am not sure how to do a school assignment. I am pretty new to python and for this project, i need to have the user input a number and have the dice roll that amount of times. but i also need to keep track of how many times each number is rolled. i have found something that i would find very helpful, but im not sure how i should do it in python. I've never used java or any other program besides python. im just not sure where to start.  Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!!

link to what i have found that would come in handy:

[Dice roll array and method calling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44506687/dice-roll-array-and-method-calling)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask] for advice. Also check out [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341) The question you have in the title is not bad, but what have you already tried?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to keep count for six different numbers. Many data structures can accommodate this. For instance, a list would work. Let's say you have a function roll() that returns a random integer between 1 and 6 inclusive. Then you could use something like this:

```
count = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
rolls = 100
i = 1
while i <= rolls:
    r = roll()
    count[r-1] = count[r-1]+1
    i = i + 1
print(count)
```

What this is doing is creating a list called count with six elements, representing the number of times each number on the dice has been rolled. We then run a loop for the number of times you want to throw the dice. Each time the loop is run, a random integer is generated and stored in r. For example, say on one iteration of the loop, the random integer generated is 2. Then the count[1] is incremented (note it's count[1] and not count[2] because the list is indexed from 0 to 5). Once the loop is over you can print your list, which will show how many times each number came up.

Answer (score 0):

A place that I would start would be importing the random module to get random integers from 1-6 since they are on a standard dice.

```
import random
```

Now take the user input:

```
number = input('Enter the amount of rolls ')
```

You need to create a loop that runs the amount of times that the user picked, which turns out to be a quite simple "for" loop. Next, we need to create two random integers between 1 and 6 twice each time. The roll will be equal to those two random numbers added together:

```
for i in range(int(number)):
    first = random.randint(1,6)
    second = random.randint(1,6)
    roll = first + second
```

Now, we have to keep track of each number and how many times it was rolled. The possibilities are the numbers 2 through 12. To check the count of these numbers, I would add all of the rolls to a list and then do the list.count to check each number. The code should end up being something like this:

```
import random
number = input('Enter the amount of rolls ')

all = []
for i in range(int(number)):
    first = random.randint(1,6)
    second = random.randint(1,6)
    roll = first + second
    all.append(roll)

for i in range(2,13):
    count = all.count(i)   
    print(str(i) + ' appeared ' + str(count) + ' times!')
```

Hope this helped. I'm kind of new too so I'm in the same place as you.

Comment: Helpful tip, if someone answers you and it answered your question correctly then click the check mark on that question.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question in the title, the simplest way is with a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). Create it at the start:

```
from collections import Counter

count = Counter()
```

Then each time you roll a die, add to the count :

```
result = roll()
count[result] += 1
```

Then at the end, you have your totals. Say for example we rolled 3 ones and 2 sixes:

```
print(count)  # -> Counter({1: 3, 6: 2})
```